# Replace or trim character from Google sheets scraped by Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, google-sheets

I can't trim or replace an ' character in google sheets from data scraped by Selenium and Python.
I tried things in Selenium script like : .text.replace(""'", "") or .replace("'", "")
Aslo tried things like these in Google Sheets: =ArrayFormula(if(C2:C="'",""))
But nothing worked for me.
I attached some images. Hopefully someone can help me with this. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try this : `str.replace("'", "")` Note : arg1 as single quote in double quote, arg2 as two double without any space.

Comment: For documentation reasons please accept the answer that helped you the most or provide your feedback in order to modify it and solve your question.

Comment: @Dilip,  where would you place this in the script?

Comment: @Tom : Do you want to process the string after it saved to google sheet or before. Or you just want to change the formatting of the cell from string to number?

Comment: @Dilip, when possible before it saves the data in google sheets

Comment: Hi ! What tool are you using for inserting this data into Google Sheets? Are you using Sheets API? What type of solution are you looking for : Google Sheets formula, Apps Scripts, Google Sheets ...?

Answer (score 1):

### Google Sheets:

Try this formula in Google sheets to get rid of all the non-digit characters:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\D+", "")
```

or as an ArrayFormula:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"\D+", ""))
```

---

### Python:

Replace this:

```
row = [id, name, q_in_stock]
```

with this:

```
row = [id, name, q_in_stock.replace("'", "")]
```

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately, but thank you for your help

Comment: @Tom the Google sheets solution works anyway. You can try and use it and then copy the output value to a different cell and you will see that it is without the symbol.

Comment: thanks, the copy works, but the data is seen as "0" in google sheets

Comment: @Tom I can not reproduce that. Post a screenshot in your question.

Comment: I added screenshots to the post. On the 1st one you can see that I added a column with the formula, and the copy works. On the 2nd where I want to use the data  you can see that the data is seen is "0"

Comment: @Tom I can't see where the data is seen as "0".

Comment: it's in the last (4th) screenshot I attached. It's the last column (deliveo-stock). It's "0" and it should be like the columns left to it (5, 8 etc). Could it be the scraped data is a specific character (code)?